Started getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener
I’ve started getting an error when the Unity app runs on an Android device, on UnityPurchasing Initialize
Unity 2022.3.181, In App Purchasing 4.12.2, Target API 34
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener
at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.FindClass (System.String name) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass._AndroidJavaClass (System.String className) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy..ctor (System.String javaInterface) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at UnityEngine.Purchasing.GooglePurchaseUpdatedListener..ctor (UnityEngine.Purchasing.Interfaces.IGoogleLastKnownProductService googleLastKnownProductService, UnityEngine.Purchasing.Interfaces.IGooglePurchaseCallback googlePurchaseCallback, UnityEngine.Purchasing.Interfaces.IGooglePurchaseBuilder purchaseBuilder, UnityEngine.Purchasing.IGoogleCachedQueryProductDetailsService googleCachedQueryProductDetailsService, UnityEngine.Pur

I tried to add a custom proguard with -keep class com.android.billingclient.** {*; } but that didn't change anything
Any hints on how to fix it?

I have the same problem exactly. Also tried to modify proguard since I had a similar problem in the past - but this time without success. Could you find the problem?

@jose yes, I solved it - check the answer below. It was a problem in gradle file in my case

Somehow (generated?) this was added to mainTemplate.gradle file
   // ** ADD THIS **
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.android.billingclient', module: 'billing'
}

I removed this exclude command and the issue was solved.

You seem to be using an outdated billing-client dependency, in combination with a billing implementation, which runs against a newer version of that library. This might be the result of a half-hearted update, where the library wasn't updated. Maybe you have that outdated library still somewhere in a local cache?
As the documentation states (the current version would be 7.0.0):

Reminder: By Aug 31, 2024, all new apps and updates to existing apps must use Billing Library version 6 or newer.

The changelog of the Unity package is not telling which version is contained.

Change log says this at 4.12
"GooglePlay - Billing Library updated to 6.2.1 (was previously 5.2.1). No new feature support was added. Subscriptions must still have only 1 base plan."

ou seem to be using an outdated billing-client dependency, in combination with a billing implementation, which runs against a newer version of that library. This might be the result of a half-hearted update, where the library wasn't updated. Maybe you have that outdated library still somewhere in a local cache?
As the documentation states (the current version would be 7.0.0):
Reminder: By Aug 31, 2024, all new apps and updates to existing apps must use Billing Library version 6 or newer.
The changelog of the Unity package is not telling which version is contained.

In my case “Remove Property Tag” setting in Admob SDK has to be unchecked to make it work.
